# sqlite update column based on previous value in other column

Tags: sqlite

I have table with a Names, Date, and Previous Date columns.  I need a function that will make Previous Date equal to the previous row's Date if the Name is the same.

By previous, I mean the most recent chronological date before the date listed,  so if I had March 5, March 29, March 17, and March 10, then March 5th would have no Previous Date, March 10th would have March 5th, March 17th would have March 10th, and March 29th would have March 17th.

So, if the first name is John with a Date of 1/1/2020 and Previous Date would be blank as there is no prior entry.  If the second name is John than regardless the Date, it would have a Previous Date of 1/1/2020.  If the third name is anything but John, the Previous Date will be again be blank as the names don't match.

Any help is appreciated.

Edited for clarification

Comment: The question is, what do you mean by previous? Unlike in a Excel spreadsheet, records do not have a natural order or a line number. They are unrelated unless you define an order based on some column(s). Based on which column(s) do you determine which record holds the previous value?

Comment: Edited OP for clarification

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `LAG()` window function.

If you want a query that returns the previous date:

```
SELECT Names, Date,
       CASE WHEN Names = LAG(Names) OVER (ORDER BY Date) THEN LAG(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Date) END PreviousDate
FROM tablename
```

If you want to update the table:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT Names, Date,
         CASE WHEN Names = LAG(Names) OVER (ORDER BY Date) THEN LAG(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Date) END Previous_Date
  FROM tablename
)
UPDATE tablename AS t
SET Previous_Date = (SELECT c.Previous_Date FROM cte c WHERE (c.Names, c.Date) = (t.Names, t.Date))
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a4f3dd2bfd58cb041a5b6c03c9a6c097).

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ you can use the `UPDATE...FROM` syntax:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT Names, Date,
         CASE WHEN Names = LAG(Names) OVER (ORDER BY Date) THEN LAG(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Date) END Previous_Date
  FROM tablename
)
UPDATE tablename AS t
SET Previous_Date = c.Previous_Date
FROM cte AS c
WHERE (c.Names, c.Date) = (t.Names, t.Date)
```